# Set zoom ratio of a displayed image in an android canvas

Tags: android, graphics, transformation

I am trying to write an android app that lets me draw graphics on top of an image then scale and zoom the image with the graphics staying over the same place on the image that have been drawn on top of it while changing the graphics in real time.

However I have been having a lot of issues actually getting it to zoom in while maintaining the center of the image.  I have written code where I have a thread that updates the image.  Updates are passed in using a class that I created called "PendingUpdate" through an ArrayBlockingQueue.  This update contains a desired zoom level which is supposed to be the ratio of the image pixels to the canvas pixels and an image center.  However the following code makes it pan while I am zooming which confuses me.

```
//Scale the image
canvas.scale(pendingUpdate.getZoom(), pendingUpdate.getZoom());

//Translate the image
double updateCx = pendingUpdate.getCenter().getX();
double updateCy = pendingUpdate.getCenter().getY();
double halfCanvasWidthInImagePixels = pendingUpdate.getZoom()*(canvas.getWidth()/2);
double halfCanvasHeightInImagePixels = pendingUpdate.getZoom()*(canvas.getHeight()/2);
double imageTranslateX = updateCx - halfCanvasWidthInImagePixels;
double imageTranslateY = updateCy - halfCanvasHeightInImagePixels;
canvas.translate(-(float)imageTranslateX, -(float)imageTranslateY);
canvas.drawBitmap(pendingUpdate.getImage(), matrix, new Paint());
```

Thank you for the help!

Edit: here is the full function, I can also post PendingUpdate if this helps, however its just a data class.

```
    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas, PendingUpdate pendingUpdate) {
        int iWidth = pendingUpdate.getImage().getWidth();
        int iHeight = pendingUpdate.getImage().getHeight();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //TODO: add scrolling functionality to this
        if(pendingUpdate.getZoom()>0) {

            //Scale the image
            canvas.scale(pendingUpdate.getZoom(), pendingUpdate.getZoom());

            //Translate the image
            double updateCx = pendingUpdate.getCenter().getX();
            double updateCy = pendingUpdate.getCenter().getY();
            double halfCanvasWidthInImagePixels = pendingUpdate.getZoom()*(canvas.getWidth()/2);
            double halfCanvasHeightInImagePixels = pendingUpdate.getZoom()*(canvas.getHeight()/2);
            double imageTranslateX = updateCx - halfCanvasWidthInImagePixels;
            double imageTranslateY = updateCy - halfCanvasHeightInImagePixels;
            canvas.translate(-(float)imageTranslateX, -(float)imageTranslateY);
            canvas.drawBitmap(pendingUpdate.getImage(), matrix, new Paint());

        }else {
            //matrix.postTranslate(canvas.getWidth()-iWidth/2, canvas.getWidth()-iHeight/2);
            canvas.drawBitmap(pendingUpdate.getImage(),
                    (canvas.getWidth()-iWidth)/2,
                    (canvas.getHeight()-iHeight)/2, null);
        }
        //TODO: draw other stuff on canvas here such as current location

    }
```

edit 2: This is how I finally got it to work, it was simply a matter of scaling it before translating it.

```
    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas, PendingUpdate pendingUpdate) {
        int iWidth = pendingUpdate.getImage().getWidth();
        int iHeight = pendingUpdate.getImage().getHeight();

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //TODO: add scrolling functionality to this
        if(pendingUpdate.getZoom()>0) {

            //Scale the image
            canvas.save();
            double updateCx = pendingUpdate.getCenter().getX();
            double updateCy = pendingUpdate.getCenter().getY();
            double halfCanvasWidthInImagePixels = (canvas.getWidth()/2);
            double halfCanvasHeightInImagePixels = (canvas.getHeight()/2);
            double imageTranslateX = updateCx - halfCanvasWidthInImagePixels;
            double imageTranslateY = updateCy - halfCanvasHeightInImagePixels;
            //canvas.scale(pendingUpdate.getZoom(), pendingUpdate.getZoom(), (float)pendingUpdate.getCenter().getX(), (float)pendingUpdate.getCenter().getY());

            canvas.scale(pendingUpdate.getZoom(),
                    pendingUpdate.getZoom(),
                    canvas.getWidth()/2,
                    canvas.getHeight()/2);

            canvas.translate(-(float)imageTranslateX,
                    -(float)imageTranslateY);
            canvas.drawBitmap(pendingUpdate.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

            canvas.restore();
        }else {
            //TODO: update this so it displays image scaled to screen and updates current zoom somehow
            canvas.drawBitmap(pendingUpdate.getImage(),
                    (canvas.getWidth()-iWidth)/2,
                    (canvas.getHeight()-iHeight)/2, null);
        }
        //TODO: draw other stuff on canvas here such as current location    
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `matrix`? where is it defined? please show more code.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have updatedthe full function definition.  Matrix is an empty matrix that the drawBitmap function requires.  I have tried applying the transformations to this matrix instead of the canvas and it seems to do the same thing.

Comment: I should also add that the pendingUpdate.center value is not modified at all and the pendingUpdate.zoom is adjusted in the range of 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use the `Canvas.scale(float sx, float sy, float px, float py)` method which does exactly what you want.

However looking at your code I think you might be messing with too many transformations at once, which is harder to debug.

1. Always (and I mean *always*) call `Canvas.save()` and `Canvas.restore()` on the initial matrix you're getting in `Canvas` if you plan to alter it. This is because the `Canvas` that you get to draw on may be the canvas for e.g. the whole window with just clipping set to the boundaries of the control that is currently drawing itself.
2. Use matrix transformation method provided by the `Canvas` method and draw bitmap using the simplest invocation.

Following these two advices look at the whole `View` I have just made up, that scales the `bitmap` by a factor of `3` with point `(16,16)` set as the pivot (unchanged point - center of scaling). Tested - working.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    Bitmap bitmap;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float sx = 3;
        float sy = 3;
        float px = 16;
        float py = 16;
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(sx, sy, px, py);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have trimmed down my code significantly and believe I have it working now.  I am not sure I understand what canvas.save() and restore() are doing though.  Is this independant of locking and unlocking and posting?

Comment: `save` and `restore` push and pop current matrix that canvas has onto a stack, similar to what you have in OpenGL. the thing is, unless you're absolutely sure that nothing draws to the canvas after you, you need to restore the matrix to the state it was when you started drawing. that's because the canvas you're drawing to is most likely shared by all views in your current window. you can test this by simply calling `canvas.setMatrix(null);` to load an identity matrix and seeing the (weird) results :>

Comment: That makes sense.  Next question, how do you set it to center on a given point and zoom in on it.  If I set the pivot point to the center of the image it pivots there but the canvas is still centered on the same spot so it just flies by, if I try to translate it, then it seems to do odd things when I zoom in.

Comment: what do you mean by "canvas is still centered on spot" and "flies by"?I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. can you draw it and upload? or edit the question and include an ascii art or matrix-style operation description like: "`output = T S input` where `T` is bla and `S` is bla" etc.

Comment: So I have an image that I am trying to display, I pass that in through pendingUpdate.getImage() I have also designated a point on the image within the update in pixels that I want to be in the center of the display with pendingUpdate.getCenter().  I have a zoom level that defines how much I want it zoomed in on that point.  I am just not understanding how the pivot point changes when I try to translate the image over to center on it I think.

Comment: I know, I understand that from the code in question, but I don't understand what for do you want to translate the image in the end. `scale(sx,sy)` around a point `(px,py)` is simply done as a series: `translate(px,py); scale(sx,sy); translate(-px,-py);` under the hood. simply grab any matrix transformation guide like this: http://people.bath.ac.uk/sej20/transform.html to understand how to combine basic operations to get the desired effect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23871/discussion-between-andr-and-fearthecron)

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  I am going to read through that and do some stepping through code and see if I can understand what is going on.  I think I may just have my thought process out of order.

Comment: WOOHOO! I finally got it working.  Thank you for all the help!  I posted what I finally wrote.  I think it was just a matter of figuring out which coordinates it was looking for and which order to do it in.

Comment: good, I'm glad you got it working. oh and thanks for sharing the solution, odds are someone someday will benefit from it :) happy coding! :)